# How to query pubsub.topics.list permission on PubSub project topics / specific topic

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to check whether the running code has permission to do "pubsub.topics.list" in the specific project.
This code:

```java
try (TopicAdminClient admin = getTopicAdmin()) {
    List<String> existing = admin.testIamPermissions("projects/my-proj/topics/my-topic",       
      Collections.singletonList("pubsub.topics.list")).getPermissionsList();
}
```

throws `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Permission pubsub.topics.list is not valid for this resource.`

When I replace `"projects/my-proj/topics/my-topic"` with `"projects/my-proj/topics"` or `"projects/my-proj"`

it throws: `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource name given`, and from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#resource_names) it looks like the only valid resource names are `"projects/my-proj/topics/my-topic" and "projects/my-proj/subscriptions/my-sub"`

What is the proper way to test for pubsub.topics.list permissions?

Comment: My guess would be that the permission "pubsub.topics.list" is to be performed against a project rather than a specific topic.  Maybe this article might be of use ... https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#tbl_perm, `pubsub.topics.list` is a permission on a Cloud project. The Cloud Pub/Sub service does not manage permissions on Cloud projects. Rather, the Resource Manager service manages permissions on Cloud projects. See https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj and https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions.